# Python doesn't find any installed modules

Tags: python

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ge7R.png)

It does this for every module that I try to import?
I put everything that is needed in path.

Comment: Try to install package with pip `pip install numpy`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\anaconda\envs\visualization-env\lib\site-packages (1.15.2)

Comment: Maybe you have to run your script from the anaconda environment (maybe anaconda create a virtual environment for dependency management and project isolation).

Comment: I'm doing that and I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can install using command prompt. Open command prompt and type `pip install numpy`

Comment: Installed via CMD, but I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' "

Comment: You've to open cmd in the scripts folder of the python

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\cosmin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.21.3)

Comment: Do you know the exact location of your python 3.7 folder?? For example, in my computer, it is C:\Users\ Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts . Like this, you've to open the scripts of the python folder, and then type cmd and enter pip install numpy in cmd

Comment: Yep, I'm opening a powershell here, type "pip install numpy", and it installs numpy in here 
 c:\users\cosmin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.21.3)

Comment: I have faced similar issues in the past . This could happen if you have multiple versions of python installed . Check which python are you using and which location has this package been installed . Both should point the same . 1) which python 2) python -V 3) pip show numpy

Answer (score 0):

apparently you are using anaconda make sure you are in the correct profile, if you are already I suggest you try using pycharm to create a virtual even, or even try to install any module locally

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).